# How to use ModelView on different Fragments to get the input of an EditText and set a TextView to its value?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewmodel

So basically what I want to achieve is to display the input of an EditText into a TextView of another Fragment. So a user answers a question and clicks on a button which gets him to the next fragment where in a TextView his answer should be displayed. Since I have 3 questions with the same method I am using ModelView to achieve this. Since I am relatively new to programming I don't know if this is the right way I implemented this. Your help is much appreciated!

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {


private HashMap<Integer, MutableLiveData<String>> answers = new HashMap<>();

public MutableLiveData<String> getAnswer(int questionId) {
    return answers.get(questionId);
}

public void setAnswer(int questionId, String answer) {
    if (answers.get(questionId) != null) {
        answers.get(questionId).setValue(answer);
    }
}
}
```

Here is my first Fragment with the first Question:

```
   ...

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_1, container, false);

        btnNavFrag1 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_question1);

        mEditTextQuestion1 = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_question_1);

        btnNavFrag1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                viewModel.getAnswer(1);

                ((GameActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(2);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getAnswer(1).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable CharSequence charSequence) {
                mEditTextQuestion1.setText(charSequence);
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is my Answer overview Fragment which is displayed after the first question Fragment and the typed in answer should replace the default value of a TextView:

```
   ...

    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_answer_1, container, false);

        btnNavFragAns1 = view.findViewById(R.id.next_question_1);

        tv_answer1 = view.findViewById(R.id.answer_player_1_text_view);

        btnNavFragAns1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ((GameActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(3);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getAnswer(1).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable CharSequence charSequence) {
                tv_answer1.setText(charSequence);
            }
        });
    }
    }

Currently I get a NullPointerException at this line:

    viewModel.getAnswer(1).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
```

Comment: please provide the LogCat

Comment: try to move onActivityCreated code into onCreate of fragment

Comment: It still shows the same error after moving code to onCreate

Comment: I need to initialize the map in the ViewModel but I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long trying I found the right solution to my problem:

I am using a ViewModel so the 6 different fragments can store and retrieve data in the functions of the ViewModel. So basically if you have a fragment where you have for example an EditText and want to display its input in another fragment, this is the way that worked for me:

1. Create a ViewModel with set and get methods:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {


    private MutableLiveData<String> mAnswer1 = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<String> mAnswer2 = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<String> mAnswer3 = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void setAnswer1 (String answer1){
        mAnswer1.setValue(answer1);
    }

    public void setAnswer2 (String answer2){
        mAnswer2.setValue(answer2);
    }

    public void setAnswer3 (String answer3){
        mAnswer3.setValue(answer3);
    }

    public LiveData<String> getAnswer1(){
        return mAnswer1;
    }
    public LiveData<String> getAnswer2(){
        return mAnswer2;
    }
    public LiveData<String> getAnswer3(){
        return mAnswer3;
    }
}
```

2. In the fragment where you have an EditText and want to use its input, you have to call the set method of the ViewModel.:

```
// This method gets the input of the EditText and "sends" it to the SharedViewModel where the next fragment can access it
    @Override public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        EditText nameEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_question_1);

        // Add Text Watcher on name input text
        nameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                viewModel.setAnswer1(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And before the onCreate method you have to call this:

```
public FragmentQuestion1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of this fragment
     * @return A new instance of fragment FirstFragment.
     */
    public static FragmentQuestion1 newInstance() {
        return new FragmentQuestion1();
    }

    @Override public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // init ViewModel
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    }
```

3. In the fragment where you want to use the input, you just have to call the get method of the ViewModel:

```
// Gets the answer from player 1 from the previous fragment and set the TextView to the answer
    @Override public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        tv_answer1 = view.findViewById(R.id.answer_player_1_text_view);

        viewModel.getAnswer1().observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                tv_answer1.setText(s);
            }
        });
    }
```

And like in the other fragment before you have to call the following before the onCreate method:

```
/**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of this fragment.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment SecondFragment.
     */
    public static FragmentAnswer1 newInstance() {
        return new FragmentAnswer1();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // initialise ViewModel here
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    }
```

I hope this will somehow help somebody because I struggled for a long time to find the right answer to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular part of code: You don't have any value set for **get answer on key 1**, you should first put **MutableLiveData** for key **"1"**:

```
viewModel.getAnswer(1)
```

First you have to put something as key 1 in `private HashMap<Integer, MutableLiveData<String>> answers = new HashMap<>();`:

```
answers.put(1, new MutableLiveData<String>());
```

Afterwards you can access mutable live data via code: `viewModel.getAnswer(1)`

Comment: I added the code like this private HashMap<Integer, MutableLiveData<String>> answers = new HashMap<Integer, MutableLiveData<String>>(){
        answers.put(1, new MutableLiveData<String>());
    };  But there is an error in the answers.put

Comment: @Kaiser you should add this code in constructor, or somewhere else, no as body of variable. Please check details about using HashMap, fro example you can see here, how to use it, this is just one of plenty links..
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setAnswer(int questionId, String answer) {
    if (answers.get(questionId) != null) {
        answers.get(questionId).setValue(answer);
    }
}
```

Error in init of LiveData.
You are accessing it without initializing inside in OnActivityCreated(). 
first init your mutablelivedata.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an example how to realize your issue with ViewModel.

ViewModel

```java
public class ViewModel_RoutineStartConnection extends AndroidViewModel{

public ViewModel_RoutineStartConnection(
      @NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
  }

private MutableLiveData<String> sAnswer = new MutableLiveData<>();

public void setAnswer(String sAnswer){
 this.sAnswer.post(sAnswer);
}

public LiveData<String> getsAnswer(){
return this.sAnswer;
}

}
```

Fragment with EditText to set Value

```java
public class Fragment_getAnswer extends Fragment {

private ViewModel_RoutineStartConnection myViewModle;
private EditText edittext;

@Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(
      @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup container,
      @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT, container, false);

edittext = root.findViewById(R.id.YOURID);
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(listener);

return root;
}

@Override
  public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    myViewModle = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ViewModel_RoutineStartConnection.class);

  }

public TextView.OnEditorActionListener listener = new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
      if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
         myViewModle.setAnswer(edittext.getText.toString);
      }
      return false;
    }
  };
}
```

The Fragment Reading the value

```java
public class Fragment_setAnswer extends Fragment {

private ViewModel_RoutineStartConnection myViewModle;
private TextView textview;

@Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(
      @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup container,
      @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT, container, false);

textview= root.findViewById(R.id.YOURID);

return root;
}

@Override
  public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    myViewModle = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ViewModel_RoutineStartConnection.class);
 myViewModle.getsAnswer.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), obs_getsAnswer):
  }

private Observer<String> obs_getsAnswer= new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable String sAnswer) {
      textview.setText(sAnswer);
    }
  };

}
```

To use this method for all answers, I suggest to add an "id" to every answer.
so when you set `setAnswer("01" + answerText)`

when you observe the data you can just use:

```java
switch(sAnswer.subString(0,3)){
case "01":
//set answer text for answer 1
break;
```